# issues with school CA certificates in terminal

Tags: certificates

I've been having issues with pulling requests and accessing sites in terminal. gives me the certificate signed by unknown authority error.

I have followed guides to install the certificate system-wide, but I'm either doing something wrong (being new to Ubuntu still it's likely) or that guide isn't good for the ca cert I'm using.[where the guide told me to paste the [cert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRJ6L.png). I hope I can find someone that actually knows what they are doing to tell me what I'm doing horribly wrong. The cert file is pasted in the certificates folder before I updated the certificates using the commands below.

I used this line of commands to try install the cert:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates
sudo cp local-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

this is the output of the commands [screenshot of terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0oe7.png)

Here is the guide I have been using: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.

Comment: does this help now?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the education-ca.cer file that you pasted into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates inside of a text editor, do you see lines near the top that start ------begin certificate------ or something similar?

If you do, then rename it to education-ca.**crt** and rerun `sudo update-ca-certificates`

If you don't, then try following the steps to convert it to a PEM format first.

Comment: It is not a Der type file but terminal refuses to convert it i tried exactly as you said but got as far as a conversion failure. When pasted into a text editor it does not show anything like what you said just signing keys or something and a bunch of corrupt characters due to the text editor not being able to fully read it. does it being a .cer file cause issues with this?

Comment: Can you paste the exact command you ran and it's output? And even though the file is .cer, it's probably der encoded. But yes, we need to get the certificate to a pem-encoded .crt file

Comment: ok i added a screenshot of the output and code lines i used. also fyi i tried renaming the file to .crt and other file types although this seems to have changed nothing.

Comment: i tried converting it and it did work now it's a .crt but i also can't copy it over for some reason it spits no errors but the file is never copied to the certificates folder.

Comment: (update) i manged to copy it over but it still has not fixed my problem i still get unknown authority errors when using the curl and wget commands.